# Most efficient way to store individual characters from string?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have an array of 300,000+ words, and the longest word is 38 characters. I am building an app that tells you the next-most likely letter based off what you've already entered. For example, as you enter the word "orange" the app will first say:

```
You entered 'o'
x.xx% of the time, the next letter is 'n'

You entered 'or'
'x.xx% of the time, the next letter is 'a'

You entered 'ora'
x.xx% of the time, the next letter is 'n'
```

And so on.

The way I've stored the data so far is like this, in a dictionary called `perc`:

Generic:

```
dict[mainkey][subkey] = subkey_value
```

Actual:

```
perc[previousLetter][letter] = percentage   # how often does letter follow previousLetter?
perc['a']['b'] = 3.15%         # 'b' follows 'a' 3.15% of the time
```

This structure is pretty parsimonious, and I'd love to be able to do the same for longer strings, like:

```
perc['ora']['n']               # 'n' follows 'ora' 0.5% of the time
```

But that dictionary would soon get really big, considering I would have to account for all permutations of 38 characters... Yikes!

What's a more effective way of doing storing longer string as the `key`?

Comment: Something like a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)?